# Is there a way to allow the apps to be displayed behind the notch when a menubar is hidden

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey

Im using Monterey with new MBP16 with notch

[image]

Is there a way to allow the apps to be displayed behind the notch when a menubar is hidden

I know about "scale to fit" feature, but i want to use all active size of screen. I understood, that center of my window will be hidden by notch, its absolutely ok

Comment: oh man, finally hunted down the right question. no solution, that's sad :/

Comment: What's the point of even hiding the menu bar if you can't maximise the program windows :/

Comment: i've looked everywhere, but still no solution (

Comment: that's THE question. Thanks for bringing that up: let's hope some programmer addresses this issue anytime soon

Comment: can somebody finally fix this)

Comment: Not that it's a real solution, but I just found this: https://notes.alinpanaitiu.com/Fullscreen%20apps%20above%20the%20MacBook%20notch

Answer (score 4):

If you are using multiple monitors you can drag a window from another monitor to the area behind the notch, and it stays there.

But as soon as you move the same window on the laptop screen even a tiny bit, it will be automatically moved below the notch (your red arrow).

This is crazy ... I hope they fix it in an upcoming macOS release ...

Comment: Wow, i dont know about multiple monitors. It looks like more llike bug. Please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Still the only way as of Sonoma 14.2!